# DEBIAN SSH Server with google authenticator. How to allow “publickey+2FA” for user1 and “password+2FA” for user2?

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd, key-authentication, 2-factor-authentication

0

The problem is very simple but I'm struggling for hours without finding the good solution.

I want "user1" to log in to the SSH server with publickey + 2FA code (but no password prompt, only 2 FA prompt)

I want "user2" to log in to the SSH server with login + password + 2 FA code (he has no publickey)

In /etc/pam.d/sshd I need to comment "include common-auth" to avoid "user1" to be prompted for his password but this also disable password prompt for "user2" which seems very insecure.

I tried different settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but nothing seems to work. The problem is that disabling the password prompt in /etc/pam.d/sshd is the only way to avoid user1 password prompt. As soon as "keyboard-interactive" method is enabled for the 2FA code, the standard password prompt is automatically handled by "keyboard_interactive" dans the old "standard password prompt" cannot be used.

Any idea to achieve what I want ?